# Rails 4 + AngularJS: App.js config and run functions don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with Rails 4 and AngularJS. I've got my app working. Controllers, directives, services, etc. However, my main `app.js` file refuses to fire the `config` and `run` functions. I've got some `console.logs` in there to test how far it gets. Here's the code:

#### angular-app/app.js

```
'use strict';

console.log('we see the app.js file'); // This works

var app = angular.module('bruno', [])

console.log(app) //This works

// This is where is stops working
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    alert('config'); // Can't see this
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
})

app.run(function () {
    console.log('App is running'); // Can't see this
});
```

Like I said, my other controllers are working just fine. The console doesn't show **any** errors and everything loads just as it should.

#### Rails application.js file:

```
//= require angular-app/app
//= require_tree ./angular-app/templates
//= require_tree ./angular-app/modules
//= require_tree ./angular-app/filters
//= require_tree ./angular-app/directives
//= require_tree ./angular-app/models
//= require_tree ./angular-app/services
//= require_tree ./angular-app/controllers
```

I've re-written this every which way I can think of, but to no avail. I'm kinda stumped. I've done it with and without the `var app`. Hoping this wonderful community can at least help me see something I can't.

---

*Additional Info*

- I'm using `gem 'angular-rails-templates'`
- Rails 4.2.3
- AngularJS 1.3.16

If you need anything else from me just ask. Who knows, maybe by tomorrow morning I'll see things differently. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I was mistakenly re-using the same module name inside another controller. Which was overwriting the module name in `app.js`. All fixed now.